# Change translation path Symfony and DDD

Tags: php, symfony, domain-driven-design

I'm building and API REST in Symfony 3 with DDD architecture. My goal is to have the following folders within ApiBundle.

- Application
- Infrastructure
- Domain
- UserInterface

I would like to have my Resources/translations/messages.en.yml file inside of UserInterface ( like: ApiBundle/UserInterface/Resources/translations/messages.en.yml), but I don't know how to notify Symfony to look for inside this folder.

I've tried to put this sample of code inside my config.yml under framework key but does not works:

```
translator:
  fallbacks: ["%locale%"]
  path: "@ApiBundle/UserInterface/Resources/config/translations"
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was

```
    framework:
            translator:
                paths:
                   - "%kernel.root_dir%/../src/ApiBundle/UserInterface/Resources/translations"
```

Answer (score 4):

You make a mistake in the config. Correct parameter is a [`paths`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#paths) (not `path`) and it accepts an array of the values:

```
# app/config/config.yml
framework:
    translator:
        paths:
            - '@ApiBundle/UserInterface/Resources/config/translations'
```

Comment: I used this config you gave it to me and the following error is shown:
@ApiBundle/UserInterface/Resources/config/translations defined in translator.paths does not exist or is not a directory


Do you know why?

Comment: you have to create that translation folder first. it has to be exist before you running cache:clear or cache:warmup